# I have an image which is running into my text even when I added clear:right

Tags: html, css, css-float

[image: Small screen view at the bottom of the page][image: very small screen]I am working on the mobile device view of my site. I'm on the contact page. The gift image (which is a clickable link) is running into my contact info on the right side and has a large gap on the left even though I set the left margin as 0. I added clear right for the image and clear left for the text. [image: medium screen view]

Also, I was having a problem where the text which was supposed to be beneath the headers was crashing into them and some was going above and partly beneath the headers. I had added a seperate id for each paragraph and added top margins for each which worked, but I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to deal with this. If there is, I would appreciate learning the better way.

You will notice that one top margin is set to 100px and a couple others are set to 120px. For some reason it was different for each line to be able to get the text beneath.

This is done within the "natural theme" Wordpress template.

Original dimensions of the gift image are: 833 ✕ 715px

I was trying out width: 5vw for the .gift it didn't seem to be working. Essentially I wanted to see which way would be best to have the gift image fit on the page according to the screen size.

Thank-you in advance.

```css
/*Contact page*/
div#page-7.post-7.page div.postarea {
    background-image: url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/unit-6/htmlcss1-img_tahoe.jpeg') !important;
    color: #C91216 !important;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

div#page-7.post-7.page div.postarea h2 {
    color: #C91216;
    float: right;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div#page-7.post-7.page div.postarea .rightside {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    clear: left;
}

div#page-7.post-7.page div.postarea h1 {
    float: right;
    clear: left;
    color: #FFEC6C !important;
    font-size: 70px !important;
}

.picjj {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.feelfree {
    color: black !important;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 520px;
    transform: rotate(-19deg);
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

.gift {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 200px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    transform: rotate(8deg);
}

#address1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    clear: left;
}

#suite {
    clear: left;
}

#gmail {
    margin-top: 120px;
    clear: left;
}

#number {
    margin-top: 120px;
    clear: left;
}

.picjj {
    border: 20px solid;
    color: rgba(255,236,108,0.60);
}

@media screen (max-width: 320px) {
    div#page-7.post-7.page
                .gift {
        width: 5vw;
        margin-left: 0;
        bottom: 300px;
        float: left;
        clear: right;
        clear: bottom;
        clear: top;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    div#page-7.post-7.page .redheaders {
        font-size: 18px !important;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
    div#page-7.post-7.page .feelfree {
        Bottom: 400px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 0;
        max-width: 80px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="contactpage">
  <div class="rightcontact"><h1 id="contactheader">Contact</h1>
  </div>        

<div class="profileimg">
<img class="picjj" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/learn-html/elements-and-structure/profile.jpg" alt="Exmaple pic" width="216">
</div>

<div class="rightside">
<h2 class="redheaders">Mailing address</h2>
<p></p>
<p id="address1">12 Skip A Few Street</p>
<p id="suite">Suite 99, Toronto, Ontario</p>
<p id="postal">M5V 1B1</p>

<h2 class="redheaders">E-mail address</h2>
<p></p>
<p id="gmail">99100@email.com</p>

<h2 class="redheaders">Phone number</h2>
<p></p>
<p id="number">123-456-7890</p>
</div>

  <div class="leftcontact">
<p class="feelfree">Feel free to check out my consumer page for fun gifts:</p>

 <a class="gift" href="https://teespring.com/stores/jjs-ts-and-stuff">
         <img src="https://www.freeimages.com/photo/present-1443957" alt="gift image for example" alt="pic for example" width="400" height="auto"><br style="clear:both;">
      </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Add a snapshot of that collision as you see on your screen. Difficult to understand by your message/text. Show snapshot.

Comment: I have added some screenshots. Looking forward to some sort of guidance. Thanks. :)